# Underline an html.H3 element in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to underline an `html.H3()` title in `dash`. My heading looks as such:

```
html.H3('Distributions', style={'font-size': '20px'})
```

How do I underline this title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you can add `css` into the `h3` element, so, [`text-decoration`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp) will help here

```
html.H3('Distributions', style={'font-size': '20px', 'text-decoration': 'underline'})
```